# Drag image from ScrollView into UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a horizontal ScrollView (Height 150) at the top of my UIViewController.  The ScrollView contains a number of UIViews (80 x 125), with each UIView containing a 64 x 64 UIImageView.

The issue I am having is dragging the UIImageView into my main UIViewController (UIView Screen).
Whenever I click and drag the image, it is hidden within the ScrollView and cannot be seen.

What am I missing so that I can drag the image out of the ScrollView and into the main UIView screen?  So that it is always shown when dragged around the screen.

Thanks

Comment: Please, share some code.

Comment: You haven't posted any sample code, so it's impossible to know for sure. One guess, though: turn off the scroll view's `clipsToBounds`.

Comment: Aaron Brager thats excellent thanks.  Turned off the ScrollViews `clipsToBounds` and it works very well.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn of the ScrollViews' `clipsToBounds` property inside the attributes inspector.